# Сайт едет в Сафари, как быть?

Tags: html, css

Сделал сайт, верстка адаптивная. Во всех браузерах отображается нормально, а в сафари, при уменьшении окна сайт едет.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как быть?
[prokitay-mebel.ru](http://prokitay-mebel.ru)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как быть? как обычно: открывать отладчик и смотреть, какие стили не работают. и там уже по месту смотреть - добавлять вендорные префиксы, переписывать свойства и т.п.

Comment: А можете навскидку сказать, что там не так? просто по стилям всё верно, префиксы стоят..

Comment: на вскидку я даже не вижу, что там плывёт

Comment: Отредактировал пост, прикрепил скрин. Это если отдалять изображение.

Comment: мне кажется, у вас по-разному рендерится шрифт в браузерах, потому в сафари он крупнее, чем должен быть, и как следствие получаем более широкий контейнер, который не влазит в сетку. выход - загрузить  другой шрифт или изменить размеры шрифта, который не вмещается

Comment: Если я изменю размеры, они будут в других браузерах меньше, а здесь ок. Есть вариант изменить шрифты для конкретного браузера?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42640/discussion-between-lexxl-and-).